# Save world transform for the same model in multiple pass rendering

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, vertex-shader, glsles

```
Input: model, bone matrix
Output: skinned model with outline and plane shadow
```

So if I want to render a model with multiple pass ( e.g. a pass to render the model itself, a pass for outline, a pass to project the model onto a plane as shadow). **I need to transform the model into world space in each pass in vertex shader** (transform with WorldMatrix and maybe skin with the bone matrix).

So **is there some way to save the transformed vertex somewhere** to save some computation?

Comment: Yes, transform feedback allows this...  but you've already explained this whole thing in a much simpler way. Use the matrices to duplicate transformation as necessary rather than reading something back.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I didn't get it. By "Use the matrices to duplicate transformation as necessary" what exactly should I do, can you explain it in more detail and make it an answer?

Comment: No, I mean that saving the results of transformation like this is not efficient. You already have the matrices you need to do the computations again on the next pass. The only time optimization strategies like this pay off are when you're dealing with per-pixel data instead of per-vertex.

Comment: Ok, maybe I have some grammar problem with the title ^-^.  I mean **save money** save in the title, to eliminate the same transform multiple times on the same model instance. But I get your opinion, you are saying what I want to do is unnecessary and inefficient.